# List all rows if catgory is selected as "ALL"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as like below:

```
Select category,blogname from table 


cat1   blog1  
cat2   blog2
cat2   blog3
cat4   blog4
cat5   blog5
```

Now if i write a query

```
select * from table where category = "cat1"
```

i get the rows for only "cat1"

```
select * from table where category = "cat2"
```

i get the rows for only "cat2"

What if i want to list all records?

```
select * from table where category = "ALL"
```

i get No rows but i need all rows.

i dont what to write a if condition , i want the condition to be in `where` clause only, that is the requirement

Comment: The question is unclear. Why can't you omit the category filter? Then you get all. Is this just another "optional parameter" question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
where (@category = 'ALL' or category = @category)
```

The variable `@category` would have the value  you are looking for.  You can see what happens if you put a value in:

```
where ('ALL' = 'ALL' or category = 'ALL')
where ('cat1' = 'ALL' or category = 'cat1')
```

Answer (score 0):

With the assumption that what you have is actually a parametrised query with `@CategoryParameter` as a parameter, what you need to do is:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE category = @CategoryParameter
  OR category IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should place the value of the one you are looking for into a variable and then........

```
Declare @searchCat Varchar(50) = 'All';

select * from 
table 
where 
  category = @searchCat
  or @searchCat = 'All';
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE category like 'cat%'

This is one option if you have logic names: cat1 ... to catN

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table where (@category = 'ALL' or category = @category)
```